# How to access camera in my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi I am new in iphone. I want developing a application that we can capture image from iphone camera.

How to do this i am not understand. Plz help me how to do this with source code and link where we can read this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the UIImagePickerController class:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIImagePickerController

There's two tutorials here:

http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/
http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/

Another SO thread here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more